# isntanceof weirdly doesn't compile when using java generics

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, instanceof

Can someone explain to me why the first instanceof evaluation doesn't compile, but the second one does compile and run perfectly??

```
private <C extends ClassA, E extends ClassB & InterfaceB> C 
    doSomething(Class<C> clazz, E entity)
{
    if(entity instanceof SomeEntity){ // This line doesn't compile.
        System.out.println();
    }

    Object tmp = entity;
    if(tmp instanceof SomeEntity){  // This line compiles and runs perfectly.
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is SomeEntity a subtype of either ClassB or InterfaceB?

Comment: @DavidtenHove my bad, removed.

Comment: @DavidtenHove, yes, it is a subtype of ClassB and implements InterfaceB

Comment: OK, well what does the error say?

Comment: I tried reproducing your problem, but it is be working fine for me (except that your method does not return anything). Can you add your class/interface structure to the question?

Comment: This method compiles just fine for me, but I had to replace your classes and interfaces since I don't have access to them. 
Need more context i.e. what is the definition of `SomeEntity`.

Comment: Without providing the interface hierarchy nor the compilation error message this question cannot reasonably be answered.